# Set a field to required in html when an option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, webforms, camunda

Hi I am trying to make a field required when option is selected like if option 1 is selected so field one will be required and if option 2 then field 2 and make field 1 not required so on. So far I have tried setAttribute, removeAttribute, getelemenybyid(..).required=true or false (proper camel cases are used in code). nothing seem to work.to better explain I have entered the code below. I am using this form as Camunda embedded form and scripts are java scripts. smaple below

```
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for="AmendmentType" >Amendment Type: </label>
<select class="form-control" onchange="Optionselection(this);" cam-variable-name="AmendmentType" cam-variable-type="String" id = "AmendmentType" required>
  <option onClick="Optionselection()" id="update" name="AmendmentType" value="Update a field">Update a field</option>
  <option onClick="Optionselection()" id="DuplicateId" name="AmendmentType" value="Duplicate Tax Files (to be mande inactive)">Duplicate Tax Files (to be made inactive)</option>
</select>
  </div>
```

```
function Optionselection(that) {
   if (that.value == "Update a field") {
        document.getElementById('ValueinSystem').required=true;
        document.getElementById('duplicateID').required=false;
}
   else if(that.value == "Duplicate Tax Files (to be mande inactive)") {
        document.getElementById('ValueinSystem').required=flase;
        document.getElementById('duplicateID').required=true;

}
```

as i said i tried the following nothing seems to work

```
function Optionselection(that) {
   if (that.value == "Update a field") {
        document.getElementById('ValueinSystem').setAttribute('required','');
        document.getElementById('duplicateID').removeAttribute('required');
}
   else if(that.value == "Duplicate Tax Files (to be mande inactive)") {
        document.getElementById('duplicateID').setAttribute('required','');
        document.getElementById('ValueinSystem').removeAttribute('required');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Selects and makes the respective input field required, to distinguish added some style

[More on client side validation here .......](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

```js
const carsNode = document.querySelector("#cars");
const merc = document.querySelector("#merc");
const audi = document.querySelector("#audi");
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const mercError = document.querySelector('#merc + span.error');
const audiError = document.querySelector('#audi + span.error');
const carError = document.querySelector('#cars + span.error');

let selectedCar;

cars.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // we listen to change event for select
  selectedCar = e.target.value;
  switch (selectedCar) {
    case "mercedes":
      merc.required = true;
      audi.required = false;
      break;
    case "audi":
      merc.required = false;
      audi.required = true;
      break;
    default:
      merc.required = false;
      audi.required = false;
      break;
  }
})

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // if the field's is valid, we let the form submit
  if ((!merc.validity.valid && selectedCar === "mercedes") || (!audi.validity.valid && selectedCar === "audi") || !selectedCar) {
    // If it isn't, we display an appropriate error message
    showError();
    // Then we prevent the form from being sent by canceling the event
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

function showError() {
  if (merc.validity.valueMissing && selectedCar === "mercedes") {
    // If the field is empty,
    // display the following error message.
    mercError.textContent = 'You need to enter a Mercedes value';
    carError.textContent = '';
    audiError.textContent = '';
    // Set the styling appropriately
    mercError.className = 'error active';
    audiError.classList.remove('error', 'active');
    carError.classList.remove('error', 'active');
  } else if (audi.validity.valueMissing && selectedCar === "audi") {
    audiError.textContent = 'You need to enter an Audi value';
    mercError.textContent = '';
    carError.textContent = '';
    // Set the styling appropriately
    audiError.className = 'error active';
    mercError.classList.remove('error', 'active');
    carError.classList.remove('error', 'active');
  } else {
    mercError.classList.remove('error', 'active');
    audiError.classList.remove('error', 'active');
    carError.textContent = 'You need to select a car';
    mercError.textContent = '';
    audiError.textContent = '';
    carError.className = 'error active';
  }

}
```

```css
input:required {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

p * {
  display: block;
}


/* This is our style for the invalid fields */

input:invalid {
  border-color: #900;
  background-color: #FDD;
}

input:focus:invalid {
  outline: none;
}


/* This is the style of our error messages */

.error {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #900;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.error.active {
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form novalidate>
    <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

    <select name="cars" id="cars">
      <option value="" selected>Select Car</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="merc">Mercedes:</label>
    <input type="text" id="merc" name="merc">
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    <br><br>
    <label for="audi">Audi:</label>
    <input type="text" id="audi" name="audi">
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    <br><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: but this will allow the form to submit even when the field is empty right??

Comment: yes this will allow to submit, as per the ask of setting required I have put it so, if you need  a form validation, it will require some more steps to check each fields, and its better to have server side validation too

Comment: ok how do i get validation?? any samples??

Comment: based on the expected behavior you require

Comment: can u share some sample code which might be helpful??

Comment: sure will do it

Comment: @ParthDatwani please check ...

Comment: hi i cannot see anything after please check....

Comment: cannot set anything after ??

Comment: I Cant see whole comment